# calculations for different columns in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array with filled with some values (column 0) and zeros (rest of the columns). I would like to do pretty much the same as I do with MS excel but using numpy, meaning to put into the rest of the columns values from calculations based on the first column. Here it is a MWE:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(20, dtype=np.int8).reshape(4,5)

b = [1, 2, 3, 4]

b = np.array(b)

a[:, 0] = b

# don't change the first column
for column in a[:, 1:]:
    a[:, column] = column[0]+1
```

The expected output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=int8)
```

The resulting output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Print the value of `column1 in the iteration.  Is it the column value or index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looping is slow and there is no need to loop to produce the array that you want:

```
>>> a = np.ones(20, dtype=np.int8).reshape(4,5)
>>> a[:, 0] = b
>>> a
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [3, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [4, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int8)
>>> np.cumsum(a, axis=1)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

#### What went wrong

Let's start, as in the question, with this array:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

Now, using the code from the question, let's do the loop and see what `column` actually is:

```
>>> for column in a[:, 1:]:
...   print(column)
... 
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
```

As you can see, `column` is not the index of the column but the actual values in the column.  Consequently, the following does not do what you would hope:

```
a[:, column] = column[0]+1
```

#### Another method

If we want to loop (so that we can do something more complex), here is another approach to generating the desired array:

```
>>> b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.column_stack([b+i for i in range(5)])
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: Good start but `np.cumsum` approach doesn't work if `a` is zeroes.

Comment: @Kasramvd Good comment but notice that that is why I created `a` with ones in it when using `cumsum`.

Comment: @John1024 Thanks for the explanation. But what if I want to make more elaborated calculations rather than sum 1?

Comment: Maybe that's not what OP want's. Besides it's interesting to solve that too :).

Comment: @david_doji I just added to the answer another method that could be extended to do something more elaborate than sum ones.

Comment: @John1024 thanks once again! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `column` is a little ambiguous: in `for column in a[:, 1:]`, it is treated as a column and in the body, however, it is treated as index to the column. You can try this instead:

```
for column in range(1, a.shape[1]):
    a[:, column] = a[:, column-1]+1

a
#array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
#       [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
#       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=int8)
```